# The table doesn't update when using sort and filter pipe angular 5

Tags: angular, sorting, filter, pipe

I am using angular version 5 here is my HTML code

```
 <h2 class="h5 mb-1">Results ({{companies.length}})</h2>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date Created <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true" (click)="sortByDate()"></i></th>
            <th>Name <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true" (click)="sortByName()"></i></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dateCreated" name="dateCreared" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nameCompany" name="name" #nameCompanyInput class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let company of companies | orderByDate:'desc' | filterCompany:nameCompany:dateCreated" (click)="goEditPage(company.ObjectID) ">
            <td>{{ company.ObjectCreated | date:chartDate }}</td>
            <td>{{ company.Name }}</td>
            <td class="text-center ">
              <a class="btn btn-primary ">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right "></i>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p *ngIf="companies.length==0 ">No data !</p>
```

When I remote the "filterCompany:nameCompany:dateCreated", I can order the table with function click sortByDate and sortByName, but if I add the "filterCompany:nameCompany:dateCreated" I still can click on sortByDate() and sortByName but the table doesn't update.
Here is my Pipe Code

```
 transform(value: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
    debugger
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }

    let valueSort = [];

    if (args && args == 'desc') {
      valueSort = this.sortByDesc(value);
    }else if (args && args == 'asc') {
      valueSort = this.sortByAsc(value);
    }else {
      valueSort = this.sortByDesc(value);
    }

    return valueSort;
  }

  sortByDesc(value) {
    value.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      let date1 = new Date(a.ObjectCreated);
      let date2 = new Date(b.ObjectCreated);
      if (date1 < date2) {
          return 1;
      }else if (date1 > date2) {
          return -1;
      }else {
          return 0;
      }
    });

    return value;
  }

  sortByAsc(value) {
    value.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      let date1 = new Date(a.ObjectCreated);
      let date2 = new Date(b.ObjectCreated);
      if (date1 > date2) {
          return 1;
      }else if (date1 < date2) {
          return -1;
      }else {
          return 0;
      }
    });

    return value;
  }
```

i am trying to debugger all function still working and have no exception, please suggest me solution

Comment: Did you define your pipe as pure or impure Pipe?

Comment: i did, i define my pipe like this :
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterCompany'
})

export class FilterCompanyPipe implements PipeTransform{}

Comment: can you explan for me pure and impure pipe, i didn't know that

Comment: @Pipe({ name: 'yourPipeName',  pure: false //make it impure }) But there is a performance penalty when using impure pipes. Because the pipe is called with every change detection cycle.

Comment: could you help me fix this

Comment: create a running example on stackblitz, that would it make much easer for all to help you

Comment: ok i will do it